# Custom attributes for Files

Tags: lightning, files, chatter-file

Can I create a folder and Upload Files with Chatter API as we do for Documents object with REST API? Or Can we add a custom attribute to Files.

What my goal is, I have to categorize the files. Each file uploaded belongs to some category. I need to implement the categorization in salesforce somehow. By adding an attribute named category and saving the category name in it. Or by creating a folder with name as the category and uploading the file to it. Is it possible? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ContentVersion which supports the addition of custom fields. Go through the documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_fields.htm&type=5) and let me know if that meets your requirement.